# How to Decrypt this javascript from a website

Tags: javascript

var _0x2741=["\x69\x64","\x63\x65\x69\x6C","\x6C\x65\x76\x65\x6C"];var LoyaltyCoefficient=[0,1,4,12,24,0];var LoyaltyCoefficient1=[0,1,3,6,12,0];var LoyaltyCoefficient2=[0,1,4,12,24,0];var LoyaltyCoefficient3=[0,1,4,12,24,0];var a;var b;var c;var d;function get_loyality_max(_0xd321xa){a=(20+Math_0x2741[1]*10)*LoyaltyCoefficient[_0xd321xa[_0x2741[2]]];b=(220+Math_0x2741[1]*10)*LoyaltyCoefficient1[_0xd321xa[_0x2741[2]]];c=(15+Math_0x2741[1]*5)*LoyaltyCoefficient2[_0xd321xa[_0x2741[2]]];d=(20+Math_0x2741[1]*5)*LoyaltyCoefficient3[_0xd321xa[_0x2741[2]]];if(_0xd321xa[_0x2741[0]]==16||_0xd321xa[_0x2741[0]]==17||_0xd321xa[_0x2741[0]]==18){return b;} ;if(_0xd321xa[_0x2741[0]]==19||_0xd321xa[_0x2741[0]]==20||_0xd321xa[_0x2741[0]]==21){return c;} ;if(_0xd321xa[_0x2741[0]]==22||_0xd321xa[_0x2741[0]]==23||_0xd321xa[_0x2741[0]]==24){return d;} ;return a;} ;

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your code and be more specific with your question.

Comment: Use a beautifier, for example [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a beautifier such as http://jsbeautifier.org/ to see the code in a better way. You can also paste it in firebug or google chrome tools in order to evaluate the escaped text. For example `var _0x2741=["\x69\x64","\x63\x65\x69\x6C","\x6C\x65\x76\x65\x6C"];` means `var _0x2741=["id", "ceil", "level"]`

Answer (score 0):

This is the best that I can do, since I really don't know what is `Math_0x2741`:

```
var _0x2741 = ["id", "ceil", "level"];
var LoyaltyCoefficient = [0, 1, 4, 12, 24, 0];
var LoyaltyCoefficient1 = [0, 1, 3, 6, 12, 0];
var LoyaltyCoefficient2 = [0, 1, 4, 12, 24, 0];
var LoyaltyCoefficient3 = [0, 1, 4, 12, 24, 0];
var a;
var b;
var c;
var d;

function get_loyality_max(input) {
    a = (20 + Math_0x2741[1] * 10) * LoyaltyCoefficient[input["level"]];
    b = (220 + Math_0x2741[1] * 10) * LoyaltyCoefficient1[input["level"]];
    c = (15 + Math_0x2741[1] * 5) * LoyaltyCoefficient2[input["level"]];
    d = (20 + Math_0x2741[1] * 5) * LoyaltyCoefficient3[input["level"]];
    if (input["id"] == 16 || input["id"] == 17 || input["id"] == 18) {
        return b;
    };
    if (input["id"] == 19 || input["id"] == 20 || input["id"] == 21) {
        return c;
    };
    if (input["id"] == 22 || input["id"] == 23 || input["id"] == 24) {
        return d;
    };
    return a;
};
```